# How to pass the values in the row that i want to delete/edit to the action class from jsp in struts2 using display tag?

Tags: java, struts2, displaytag

I  want to create edit , delete link in display tag with struts2. This is my jsp code

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Contact Manager - display tag Example</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<display:table  name="contactList" requestURI="" pagesize="10" export="true" cellpadding="1" uid="sr"  cellspacing="1" size="50"
    defaultorder="ascending" sort="list" style="width:850"
     id="row">
            <display:column property="id" title="serial no" sortable="true"   />
            <display:column property="lastName" title="TV Show" sortable="true"   />
            <display:column property="firstName" title="User Name" sortable="true"  />
            <display:column property="emailId" title="Email Id" sortable="true"  />

            <display:column media="html"
    title="Delete"
    style="text-align:center">
    <s:url id="deleteUrl" action="deleteLink">
    <s:param name="id1" value="#attr.row.id" />
    </s:url>
    <s:a href="%{deleteUrl}">
         Delete
    </s:a>
</display:column>

<display:column media="html"
title="edit"
style="text-align:center">
<a href="deleteLink?id=<s:property value="id"/>">edit</a>
</display:column>

             <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="ActorDetails.xls"/>
            <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.filename" value="ActorDetails.pdf"/>
            <display:setProperty name="export.pdf" value="true" />
        </display:table>



</body>
</html>
```

this is my action class:

```
    package net.viralpatel.contact.view;

    import java.util.List;

    import net.viralpatel.contact.controller.ContactManager;
    import net.viralpatel.contact.model.Contact;

    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;


    public class ContactAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Contact>,Preparable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 9149826260758390091L;

        private Contact contact;
        private List<Contact> contactList;


        private ContactManager linkController;

        public ContactAction() {
            linkController = new ContactManager();
        }



        public String getRecords()
        {
            contactList =linkController.lSist();

            return SUCCESS;
        } 

        public String deleteRecord()
        {
           System.out.println(contact.getId());

            return SUCCESS;
        } 

        public Contact getContact() {
            return contact;
        }

        public List<Contact> getContactList() {
            return contactList;
        }

        public void setContact(Contact contact) {
            this.contact = contact;
        }

        public void setContactList(List<Contact> contactsList) {
            this.contactList = contactsList;
        }


@Override
    public Contact getModel() {

        return contact;
    }

    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        contact = new Contact();
    }
    }
```

How do I get the values of the attributes in the row which I delete from the jsp page to the deleteRecord() method in the ContactAction class??
HERE the statement

```
System.out.println("ID IS "+contact.getId());
```

gives an output: ID IS null

Please suggest some solution.

Thanks

this is the Contact bean

```
package net.viralpatel.contact.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Contacts")
public class Contact implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8767337896773261247L;

    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String emailId;
    private String cellNo;
    private Date birthDate;
    private String website;

    private Date created;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @Column(name="firstname")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    @Column(name="lastname")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    @Column(name="email_id")
    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }
    @Column(name="cell_no")
    public String getCellNo() {
        return cellNo;
    }
    @Column(name="birthdate")
    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }
    @Column(name="website")
    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }
    @Column(name="created")
    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }
    public void setCellNo(String cellNo) {
        this.cellNo = cellNo;
    }
    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }
    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }
    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, is the answer we can use the `<s:bean>` to instantiate the bean class and then `<s:param>` acts as the setter method whose values can be retrieved in the action class using getter methods of the bean class Contact

```
<display:column media="html"
    title="Delete"
    style="text-align:center">
    <s:url id="deleteUrl" action="deleteLink">
    <s:bean name="net.viralpatel.contact.model.Contact"></s:bean>
    <s:param name="id" value="#attr.row.id"></s:param>
    <s:param name="firstName" value="#attr.row.firstName"></s:param>
    </s:url>
    <s:a href="%{deleteUrl}">
         Delete
    </s:a>
</display:column>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
#attr.uidOfYourTable.property
```

in your case

```
<display:column media="html" title="edit" style="text-align:center">
   <a href="deleteLink?id=<s:property value="#attr.sr.id"/>">edit</a>
</display:column>
```

(leaving out the fact that your Edit link points to an DeleteLink Action :o)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what [the documentation](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/tagreference.html) says about the display:table tag:

> id: See "uid".
>
> uid: Unique id used to identify this table. **The object representing the current row is also added to the pageContext under this name, so that you can refer to it in column bodies using ${uid}**. You can also use uid_rowNum to refer to the current row number. Two tables in the same page can't have the same id (paging and sorting will affect both). If no "htmlId" is specified the same value will be used for the html id of the generated table.

(emphasis mine)

So choose between `id` and `uid` (and don't specify the id twice as you're doing) in your tag instead of using both, and then (assuming you keep uid), use ${sr} to refer to the current element:

```
<s:param name="id1" value="${sr.id}" />
```

Comment: This is giving org.apache.jasper.JasperException:  According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions

Comment: You probably need to pass an OGNL expression, but I don't master the OGNL syntax. Probably something like `#sr.id`

Comment: Here, is the answer we can use the <s:bean> to instantiate the bean class and then <s:param> acts as the setter method whose values can be retrieved in the action class using getter methods of the bean class Contact

Comment: <display:column media="html"
    title="Delete"
    style="text-align:center">
    <s:url id="deleteUrl" action="deleteLink">
    <s:bean name="net.viralpatel.contact.model.Contact"></s:bean>
    <s:param name="id" value="#attr.row.id"></s:param>
    <s:param name="firstName" value="#attr.row.firstName"></s:param>
    </s:url>
    <s:a href="%{deleteUrl}">
         Delete
    </s:a>
</display:column>

Answer (score 0):

you can write like:

```
     <display:column property="status" title="Status" sortable="true" paramId="aid" paramProperty="aid" href="/MsgSystem/adminread" />
```